# What means when website php link adds "?" to the end?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing a website and n the website's main page I have a floating window (like a popup inside the main page) with a button that calls a function with an `alert("hello")` just to test if it works.

The problem is that when I click the button, the JavaScript alert pops up and after I click "OK" the website reloads and appends a "?" to the end on the link!?!

Example: first I have: "www.mylink.main.php" and when I click "OK" I get "www.mylink.main.php?" and the website reloads (like if I had reloaded the browser)...

Why is this happening??

I also noticed that if I change the link to "www.mylink.main.php?#" everything seems to work fine!!

This bug is killing me lol

Comment: post us soem code or a link for more info on why it's doing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ? is a query string: 
In the World Wide Web, a query string is the part of a uniform resource locator (URL) that contains data to be passed to web applications such as CGI programs.

When a web page is requested via the Hypertext Transfer Protocol, the server locates a file in its file system based on the requested URL. This file may be a regular file or a program. In the second case, the server may (depending on its configuration) run the program, sending its output as the requested page. The query string is a part of the URL which is passed to the program. Its use permits data to be passed from the HTTP client (often a web browser) to the program which generates the web page.
[WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)
The # is a fragment identifier: 
In computer hypertext, a fragment identifier is a short string of characters that refers to a resource that is subordinate to another, primary resource. The primary resource is identified by a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI), and the fragment identifier points to the subordinate resource.

The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document. The generic syntax is specified in RFC 3986. The hash mark separator in URIs does not belong to the fragment identifier.
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier